# jQuery Remove specific span based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to remove only spans which has an id that stars with the key word "junk_"

for example if I have

```
<span id="junk_8345">A</span>
<span id="valid_2972">B</span>
<span id="junk_9249">C</span>
```

The output should look like

```
<span id="valid_2972">B</span>
```

I've tried to use

```
$("span:has(junk)").remove();
```

but it does not seem to work. I'm open to use regex expression with the replace function if I can accomplish the same goal. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use the `startswith` selector.

```
$('span[id^="junk"]').remove();
```

Comment: Just did. Sorry for being late! for some reason, I had to wait for a couple of minute before I mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what the API page give about "selectors" ( http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ), I suggest you trying to use the start with **^=**.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$('span[id^="junk"]').remove();
```

Comment: I just saw that Jim was a little bit faster than me... but, you will have the links if you want to learn more about special selectors (other than has, #id or .class)

Comment: I appreciate your answer though. Voted up!